# Grab all of the pages of a PDF using textsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am getting a pfd using the older version of itextsharp with this code

```
string Oldfile = @"C:/test.pdf"; // Gets the Template 
    (new FileInfo("C:/C:/test.pdf")).Directory.Create(); // Go create this folder if it's not there
    string NewFile = "C:/test.pdf";
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Oldfile);
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
    Document document = new Document(Size);
 //   MemoryStream memory_stream = new MemoryStream();
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(NewFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    PdfWriter weiter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
    document.Open();
    PdfContentByte cb = weiter.DirectContent;
    PdfImportedPage page = weiter.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
    //PdfImportedPage page2 = weiter.GetImportedPage(reader, 2);
    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
```

The problem I am having is when it gets that file it has 2 pages in that pdf but it only gets the 1st page and adds lines and saves the only 1st page of the pdf I want to be able to grab both of them or is there a way to merge them after wards

Comment: The question is unclear. What is "grabbing" a page? Why are you using `PdfWriter` and `AddTemplate()` to merge pages? That's so wrong? Also: you deliberately use an older version of iText, which means you have chosen for a version that is no longer supported. Why don't you upgrade?

Comment: the add template is not used to add 2 pages its used to add lines so don't worry about that I am looking. I will edit the question for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you need to iterate all pages.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace TestAnything
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> filesToMerge = new List<string> { @"c:\temp\1.pdf", @"c:\temp\2.pdf" };
            FileInfo destinationFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\merge.pdf");
            if (File.Exists(destinationFile.FullName))
                File.Delete(destinationFile.FullName);
            MergeFiles(filesToMerge, destinationFile);
        }


        public static void MergeFiles(List<string> sourceFiles, FileInfo destinationFile)
        {
            if (sourceFiles == null || sourceFiles.Count == 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("blahhh.");

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFiles[0]);
            Document document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
            PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(destinationFile.FullName, FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            try
            {
                foreach (string sourceFile in sourceFiles)
                {
                    reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);
                    reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();

                    for (int x = 1; x <= reader.NumberOfPages; x++)
                        writer.AddPage(writer.GetImportedPage(reader, x));

                    PRAcroForm form = reader.AcroForm;
                    if (form != null)
                        writer.CopyAcroForm(reader);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (document.IsOpen())
                    document.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says that the the pdfwriter does not contain the deffination of addpage

Comment: I updated my usage. I forgot to mention that writer is an instance of PdfCopy.

Comment: So the issue its giving is that the pdf is being used by other process because its been open by the pdf reader before for the process I am mainly trying to do isn't there a way we could add the second page to it after the 1st process is done

Comment: Are you merging multiple pdfs into one or just a pdf copy?

Comment: Also, it seems odd that the reader would lock the output file. Your file name is wrong --> C:/C:/test.pdf should that be C:\test.pdf?

Comment: Of the path you are seeing is not same as I have I changed it for policy purpose and I have 1 pdf that has  pages and I am getting that pdf but it only gets the 1st page only I want it to take the whole file not just the first page of that pdf document or merge it after I do changes to that file merge that with another pdf

Comment: I just update the answer with a testable version that will merge one or more pdfs having one or more pages.

Comment: let me give it a try

Comment: pdf copy does not contain a definition of copyacroform I have made a brand new page a class no there is nothing else interfering with it I have this error

Comment: Then comment that part out as it is not relevant. Runtime version ->v2.0.50727  Assembly itextsharp, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca

Comment: Ok so the problem now is there was no error but when it ran through the code it created the new file and it copied the 1st file \temp\1.pdf twice and 2 of them are same page in the new \temp\merge.pdf it has 2 identical pages

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. I have used this code in production for years without issue. Perhaps there is an advanced construct in your pdf file like a protected page or whatnot. This is all I can offer and sorry if it did not help.

Comment: There was some internal issue I found out this fixed and your code worked thanks a lot!